# postgresql group by one value but return multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

Let's say I have the following table:

```
id  location    vendor  price   qty
1     CA         nike     10    2
2     US         nike     11    1
3     US        adidas    12    2
```

I want to have a query that groups the vendors and returns `price * qty` per each location. So each location would be a column. So the result in this case would be:

```
vendor  | CA | US
------------------
 nike   | 20 | 11
 adidas | 0  | 24
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! [Here's](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a3b8b48040bf809592ef2c982a99b00) a dbfiddle you can work in that has the table setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT vendor,
       sum(qty * price) FILTER (WHERE location = 'CA'),
       sum(qty * price) FILTER (WHERE location = 'US')
FROM atable
GROUP BY vendor;
```